# php login code requires to login twice due to redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication

On a website I am working on you have to login in twice for the session variables to register. I have read it is caused when you do a header redirect.

```
function login()
{
    // secure data
    $email      = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['email']));
    $password   = md5(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['password'])));
    // sql statment
    $tbl=$this->tbl;
    $sql="SELECT id, admin, email FROM $tbl WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $result=$this->query($sql, true);
    // check if user exist
    $numRow=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numRow==1)
    {
        // login
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
            $_SESSION['admin']=$row['admin'];
        }
        // problematic redirect. http redirect erases session data?
        header('Location: http://www.website.com/');
        return true;
    }
    $this->error="logint";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where's session_start()?

Comment: session start is in my file before I include my class file and run the login method...or do I need to also include it in my class file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALWAYS `session_start()` before you set or get any session variables

Comment: I use session start in my file before I include the class and run the method. do I need to also have it in the class file?

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to send some javascript to the client that's all !

I test your dns entry for www.yamikowebs.com. Be sure also you have resolving IP on your client for test !

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the redirection is on another domain.

The constraint is to keep the data to a domain to another one.

One elegant solution is to stock information in your database, create a ticket unique just only  for this transfer as string and use the function md5() for that. for example use the a date include in a middle position in a long string. Stock it in the database with a delay of 1 minute for security.

include this to replace header

```
$tt= new DateTime();
$tt->format('Y-m-d/H:i:s');
$astring = "On a website I am working on you have to login in twice for the session variables to register. from the suggested questions I have read it is caused when you do a header redirect. possible php solutions(if none I can echo a javascript redirect";
$arandom = rand(0, (strlen($astring) - 19));
$astring = substr_replace($astring,$tt->format('Y-m-d/H:i:s'),$arandom,19);
$code =  md5($astring).crc32($astring);

// use $code to remember all information of your client in the database et reuse on demand of script associated with client0002
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
    window.location.assign('http://www.yamikowebs.com/test/client0002?acces=$code')</script>";
```

Have nice day.